# Ubuntu 16.04 - Site cannot be reached

Tags: 16.04

Started getting this message several updates ago. Before that never a problem. Now I have to edit the resolv.conf file and change server from 127.0.11 to 8.8.8.8. I have another computer that has not been updated and no problem. What changed? Why isn't this fixed?

Comment: What's the error?, which server is it?, without details is imposible to understand the problem.

Comment: He is obviously talking about DNS here because he has to change /etc/resolve.conf